# Finding Length of Longest Oscillating Subsequence

Tags: arrays, algorithm, recursion

I am trying to give a simple recursive definition that gives the length of the longest oscillating subsequence of an array. I know that I need to look at both the `X[i]` and `X[i-1]` elements, compare them and increment a counter based on what it is. (less than or greater than). I'm not sure how to make it recursive though. Would adding `LOS(max(counter1,counter2))` be the correct thing to add after the if statements to make it recursive?

Comment: Why would you stick to make it in a recursive way, if you seams to have no idea how?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to find the longest length of: X1X3<... or X1>X2...
So consider that, max_less is the longest length at index i when X[i - 1] > X[i] and max_more is the longest length at index i when X[i - 1] < X[i].
Loop to the end of array if X[j] > X[j - 1], now max_more = max_less + 1 and vice versa.
Return max(max_less, max_more)